# WPF Empty TabControl Content

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I am using a TabControl to host workspaces, with the method outlined in [This amazing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) article by John Smith. I was wondering if there is a way to add content, like an image, to the tab control when it has no tabs. Sort of a default or empty behavior. I would like to have the application logo, or maybe some helpful arrows a-la Chrome's first time use tab.

**Edit**: This might be a little more complicated. I tried Chad's solution below on a standard tabcontrol at it displayed. However, the tabcontrol I am using for the workspaces is being rendered by a content control using a datatemplate, and I couldn't get his solution working with it. HB's solution worked with some changes.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Affinity;component/Images/affinity_logo.png" Margin="20"/>
        <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}" Margin="4">
            <TabControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TabControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                        Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Style>
        <TabControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                <Grid Background="White">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                        <StackPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Margin="2,2,2,0"
                            IsItemsHost="true"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Grid.Row="1" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TabControl.Template>
    </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could overlay the TabControl on your Image and hide it if there are no items in it, e.g.

```
<Grid>
    <Image />
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                            Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Style>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Or you could swap the content of a ContentControl, also using Triggers, as in the above method both contols affect the layout. e.g.

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="Image"/>
        <TabControl x:Key="TabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
    </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource TabControl}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.Count}"
                        Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Image}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Note that here the `DataTrigger` should bind directly to the same collection used in the `TabControl`. This is because if you bind to the `TabControl.Items.Count` this binding will break the moment the trigger fires as the `TabControl` will be unloaded.

Comment: This looks very promising, I added some code to my question to show how my content control is binding to the workspaces collection. I am trying to make them both work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background to the tab control.  The XAML looks something like this:

```
<TabControl Height="290" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,350,0,0" Name="TabControl" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="481" TabIndex="200">
    <TabControl.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/EffectsViewer;component/res/someimage.png" />
    </TabControl.Background>
</TabControl>
```

Just be sure the image you use is in your resources.  Its not to hard to add using the GUI in visual studio.  As for adding controls, that might be a little more complicated.  I think to do that you would need to either hide the control behind something while its empty, OR derive from it and implement it yourself.

Comment: This assumes that the placeholder content is an image. That's clearly very limited. I would like my placeholder content to be, for example, *The Illustrated History Of The Locomotive*, complete with playable videos and animations and what not. Or, as another example, with a single tiny little line of text centered on the window saying "Nothing here yet" *in the user's preferred language*. A single image simply won't do.